# For Loop Efficiency

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

The following loop is effective in that it gets me to the finish line but i'm looking for a way to make it more efficient as I'm looping through a large dataset. Possibly using a Purrr function?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)
#### CREATE DATA
df_1 <- data.frame(Date              =   seq.Date(as.Date("2016-01-01"), length.out = 36, by = "month"),
                 Inventory           =   round(runif(36,5,100),0),
                 Purchases           =   round(runif(36,5,100),0),
                 Sales               =   round(runif(36,5,100),0),       
                 Ending_Inventory    =   round(runif(36,5,100),0)) %>%
  
      mutate(Starting_Inventory = lag(Ending_Inventory,1)) %>%
      mutate(product             = "Product_1") 

df_2 <- data.frame(Date              =   seq.Date(as.Date("2016-01-01"), length.out = 36, by = "month"),
                   Inventory           =   round(runif(36,5,100),0),
                   Purchases           =   round(runif(36,5,100),0),
                   Sales               =   round(runif(36,5,100),0),       
                   Ending_Inventory    =   round(runif(36,5,100),0)) %>%
  
  mutate(Starting_Inventory = lag(Ending_Inventory,1)) %>%
  mutate(product             = "Product_2") 
 
df <- rbind(df_1, df_2) %>% 
      group_by(product) %>%
      timetk::future_frame(
              .date_var = Date,
              .length_out = "12 months",
              .bind_data = TRUE
            )
```

Here I'm creating a date sequence to iterate through the for loop

```
#### CREATE DATE SEQUENCE
Dates <- seq(min(df$Date)  %m+% months(36), min(df$Date)  %m+% months(48), by = "month")
```

The dates from the sequence above will iterate through the loop to fill in the future data and then I join, rename some columns, and drop all that contain ("y")... Seems like I'm performing some steps that aren't necessary.

```
for (i in 1:length(Dates)){
     
  df <- df %>%
  
  mutate(Purchases          = case_when(Date < Dates[i] ~ Purchases,
                                         Date == Dates[i] ~ lag(Purchases, 12)*1.05, 
                                         TRUE ~ 0
                                         )) %>%
    
  mutate(Starting_Inventory = case_when(Date < Dates[i]  ~   Starting_Inventory,
                                              Date == Dates[i] ~ lag(Ending_Inventory,1),
                                             TRUE ~ 0
                                           )) %>%
    
  mutate(Sales            = case_when(Date < Dates[i]  ~   Sales,
                                             Date == Dates[i] ~ lag(Sales,12) * 1.15,
                                             TRUE ~ 0
                                             )) %>%
    
  mutate(Ending_Inventory = case_when(Date < Dates[i]  ~   Ending_Inventory,
                                             Date == Dates[i] ~ Starting_Inventory + Sales + Purchases,
                                             TRUE ~ 0
                                             )) %>%
    
  mutate(Inventory             = case_when(Date <  Dates[i]  ~   Inventory,
                                           Date == Dates[i] ~ Ending_Inventory, 
                                          TRUE ~ 0
    ))
                          
  new_data <- df[df$Date == (Dates[i]),]
  
  df <- df %>%
    left_join(., new_data, by = c("product", "Date")) %>%

    mutate(Inventory.x            = ifelse(Date == Dates[i],Inventory.y,Inventory.x),
           Purchases.x            = ifelse(Date == Dates[i],Purchases.y,Purchases.x),
           Sales.x                = ifelse(Date == Dates[i],Sales.y,Sales.x),
           Starting_Inventory.x   = ifelse(Date == Dates[i],Starting_Inventory.y,Starting_Inventory.x),
           Ending_Inventory.x     = ifelse(Date == Dates[i],Ending_Inventory.y,Ending_Inventory.x),
           ) %>%

    rename(Inventory              = Inventory.x,
           Purchases              = Purchases.x,
           Starting_Inventory     = Starting_Inventory.x,
           Sales                  = Sales.x,
           Ending_Inventory       = Ending_Inventory.x) %>%
    dplyr::select(-contains(".y"))
  
  return
  
  print(i)
  gc()
}
```

Comment: It's helpful if you can describe what you're trying to do, otherwise it's twice as much work for us to first infer what your code is supposed to be doing. It would also be great to show an example and explain the logic behind the desired result.

Comment: That is a completely reproducible example, i'm essentially taking actual data, creating a 12 month forecast. So i need to perform the 5 calculations in that for loop to fill in the future dates.

Comment: Is %m+% from lubridate?

Comment: Both `case_when()` and `ifelse()` are both vectorized functions and thus can be used directly without the need for the subscripts.

Comment: Is it working as you want? Shouldn't Ending inventory decrease with sales? After running it I ran `df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(product, Date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, value, color = product)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~name)` and noted that inventory gets out of control. Much more plausible if the sign is reversed before Sales in the Ending Inventory calc.

Comment: Does the Inventory column here have any significance? It seems redundant and was prepopulated randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of unnecessary steps in there.

1. Mutate can take more than one expression at once.
2. The case_when is unnecessary since in the next step you only keep the rows that got modified.
3. Then, for the same reason, the join and renaming is more steps than needed, you can just replace the old rows with the new row by selecting a subset.

```r
for (i in seq_along(Dates)){
  new_data <- df2 %>%
    mutate(Purchases = lag(Purchases, 12)*1.05,
           Starting_Inventory = lag(Ending_Inventory,1),
           Sales = lag(Sales,12) * 1.15,
           Ending_Inventory = Starting_Inventory + Sales + Purchases,
           Inventory = Ending_Inventory)
  
  df2[df2$Date == Dates[i],] <- new_data[new_data$Date == Dates[i],]
}
```

4. But then you're stil recalculating your whole data.frame for each loop. No need for that either since `mutate()` is iterative. You can do it all with just that function.
5. Also, since there are only 2 conditions really needed, you can replace the `case_when` with `ifelse` and it's faster.

```r
df <-  df %>%
      mutate(
        Purchases = ifelse(
          Date %in% Dates, lag(Purchases, 12)*1.05, Purchases
          ), 
        Starting_Inventory = ifelse(
          Date %in% Dates, lag(Ending_Inventory,1), Starting_Inventory
          ), 
        Sales = ifelse(
          Date %in% Dates, lag(Sales,12) * 1.15, Sales
          ), 
        Ending_Inventory = ifelse(
          Date %in% Dates, Starting_Inventory + Sales + Purchases, 
          Ending_Inventory
          ),
        Inventory = ifelse(
          Date %in% Dates, Ending_Inventory, Inventory
          )
      )
```

Edit:

I think it's important to break down what you're trying to do when you end up with long for loop like this. Since you're trying to do in place modifications, even in base R, you could do this with this short a for loop :

```r
df3 <- df.o
    df3 <- df3 |> within({
      for (i in which(Date %in% Dates)){
        Purchases[i] = Purchases[i-12]*1.05
        Sales[i] = Sales[i-12] * 1.15
        Ending_Inventory[i] = Starting_Inventory[i] + Sales[i] + Purchases[i]
        Inventory[i] = Ending_Inventory[i]
        Starting_Inventory[i] = Ending_Inventory[i-1]
      }
      i = NULL
    })
```

A bit slower than mutate, but it's the same logic.